# Read/Write system call reads/writes data from/to which buffer

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am working with serial port programming and i have following doubt please clear it

1. Does Read/Write system call reads and writes data directly from/to UART buffer?
2. Which buffer does Rx and Tx of  "**/proc/tty/driver/serial**" refers to.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`read()`and `write()` access data via a so called file-descriptor return by a call to `open()`.

`open()` gets passed in the name of a serial device.

Serial devices could be named `"/dev/ttySX"` with `X={0..N}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you worried about:

> Does Read/Write system call reads and writes data directly from/to
>   UART buffer?

The kernel takes care of the actual read/write calls to a file regardless if its a device or a data file, in the case of device, IOCTL calls will be made to the device in question and handle it behind the scenes.

> Which buffer does Rx and Tx of "/proc/tty/driver/serial" refers to.

Again, that is handled by the kernel and related IOCTL calls to the serial driver by way of device descriptor to the actual serial port.

If still in doubt, a refresher on serial port programming under Un*x environments such as Linux/FreeBSD would be recommended.

Comment: [meta]In all articles they have specified that read system call blocks when there are no data in buffer,but they have not mentioned in which buffer whether its User space buffer or Kernel space buffer,please clarify it.